# How to trim a string in Hugo templates

Tags: substring, hugo, go-templates

I always create my posts with filenames that begin with "0001-", "0002-", etc.  I'd like the default title to strip that off.

In the file `themes/Hugo-Octopress/./archetypes/post.md` I changed:

```
---
title: "{{ replace .TranslationBaseName "-" " " | title }}"
```

to

```
---
title: "{{ replace .TranslationBaseName "-" " " | substr 6 | title }}"
```

I thought that this would pipe the title through "substr 6" which would remove the first 5 chars from the file.

However the error message that I got was this:

```
Error: Failed to process archetype file "[redacted]/themes/Hugo-Octopress/archetypes/post.md": template: post:2:50: executing "post" at <substr 6>: error calling substr: start argument must be integer
```

How do I strip off the first 5 chars of a string in a template pipeline?

Comment: I posted a solution that works below.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to wrap your `replace` in parens and give that as a parameter to `substr`, like this:

`title: "{{ substr (replace .TranslationBaseName "-" " ") 11 | title }}"`

I tested it and this work for me.

(source: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-trim-and-truncate-a-url/2639/3)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have experienced, Hugo doesn't process any functions in *.md files normally, so you'd have to use "Shortcodes" - see those two for further information:

- https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/
- https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/can-we-use-hugo-commands-in-markdown-files/4937

I'm quite sure though that I read somewhere that these don't work in front matter, i.e. the "title" parameter.

For my posts, which are also numbered, I have resorted to the "slug" parameter:

> 001-post-title.md

```
+++
title = "post title"
weight = "-999"
slug = "post title"
image = "fancy.jpg"
+++
```

Using this parameter, the permalink looks like this in my case:

```
http://localhost:1313/post/post-title/
```

I know that this means manual typing and also may be a source of errors, but it's the easiest way around this issue I could find when I wanted a solution. Maybe there's a better answer if you ask the same thing in the Hugo forums.

Comment: I'm modifying the existing post.md file, which does work. My question is about why the addition I made doesn't work.